# How to make a query with a condition with laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

hello friends I need help, my problem is that I need to check if certain data already exist in the favorite table these can not be added again, for example a user who wants to add a promotion that has previously registered does not allow him to add it again.
but the condition that I need is that if the user with user_id = 9 entered a promotion in the favorite table with promocion_id = 30 he can not re-enter that promocion_id, but if another user with user_id = 13 wants to add that same promocion_id = 30 then this one if I can [my table favoritos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7gxq.png)

```
$promocionid = request('promocion_id');
$userid = request('user_id');
if($query = PromocionesFavoritasUsers::where('user_id',13)->where('promocion_id',30)->get())
{
    return response()->json([$query,
        'message' => 'esta promocion ya ha sido agregada anteriormente'],422);
}else{
    $agregar = new PromocionesFavoritasUsers;
    $agregar->user_id = 13;
    $agregar->promocion_id = 30;
    $agregar->save();
    return response()->json([$agregar,
    'message' => 'Se agrego con exito esta promoción'],200);

}
```

where I have put numbers, I will put the variables $ promocion id and $ user id (I put the numbers to try with postman) but I only get the message 'this promotion has already been added before'], 422

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue is here...

`if($query = PromocionesFavoritasUsers::where('user_id',13)->where('promocion_id',30)->get())`

Even if the results are empty, that condition will still evaluate to true so you should probably expand on that a little more.

```
$query = PromocionesFavoritasUsers::where('user_id',13)->where('promocion_id',30)->get()
if ($query->count() > 0) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much got this correct.  You want to check the database to see if a promotion exists against two parameters which are sent in via the `$request` object.  If so, don't allow a new promotion to be made.  The way you have it now, it is always going to return 422 since those values are already in the database and a collection is going to be a true value.

First, need to get your variables correctly from `$request`:

```
public function whateverYourFunctionIsCalled(Request $request){
    $promocionid = $request->get('promocion_id');
    $userid = $request->get('user_id');
    // Etc
}
```

Then, in that same function, call the query much as you have:

```
$exists= PromocionesFavoritasUsers::where('user_id',$userid)->where('promocion_id',$promocionid )->first();
```

Check if there was an exact match returned (non-null), and if there was, don't move forward:

```
if(isset($exists))
 {
      return response()->json([$query,
           'message' => 'esta promocion ya ha sido agregada anteriormente'],422);
  }else{ // Create a new promotion }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if($query = PromocionesFavoritasUsers::where('user_id',13)->where('promocion_id',30)->get())
```

to

```
if(PromocionesFavoritasUsers::where('user_id',13)->where('promocion_id',30)->exists())
```

`exists()` returns `TRUE` if any record satisfies the WHERE conditions. Otherwise it returns `FALSE`.